# How do I create a custom Vee-Validate rule in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vee-validate

I'm trying to create a custom VeeValidate rule for my VueJS component written in TypeScript.  The rule needs to validate two fields together following the guide at [VeeValidate - Cross Field Validation](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/cross-field-validation.html) - here's a snippet:

```html
            <div class="form-group">
                <checkbox name="noBarcode" v-model="currentProduct.noBarcode" label=" " />
                <i class="info-icon btn-base-element-icon fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="" data-original-title="Tick this checkbox if this product does not have a barcode."></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <text-input v-model="currentProdcut.barcode" label="BarCode" name="barcode" rules="barcode:@noBarcode" />
            </div>
```

Both `text-input` and `checkbox` are custom form components that incorporate `ValidationProvider` as per [Advanced Input Fields](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/refactoring-forms.html#advanced-input-fields).

My custom rule currently looks like this:

```js
extend('barcode', {
  params: ['checkbox'],
  validate(value, { checkbox }) {
    return checkbox === true || value.length > 0
  },
  message: "Please enter a barcode. If this product does not have a barcode, tick the checkbox above."
})
```

The problem is this is currently being interpreted by TypeScript with Vetur throwing the following error message (rightly so):

> Property 'checkbox' does not exist on type 'any[] | Record<string, any>'.

I haven't yet been able to find any examples of writing custom rules in TypeScript so looking for pointers there...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is legit, but what help me get rid of the error message is add an interface to the 2nd argument. Something like this

```
interface ParamI {
 [index: string]: any
}
```

and then in your validate function

```
validate(value, { checkbox }: ParamI) {
    return checkbox === true || value.length > 0
  },
```

Comment: I've gotten around it so far by doing this:  `{ checkbox }: Record<string, unknown>` but haven't yet tested it.  Will see how it goes :)